Вынесение экземпляра Bot за рамки функции main
Нужна помощь с вынесением переменной Bot за рамки функции таким образом, чтобы я мог обращаться к ней в любом другом файле проекта.
Структура файла Main:
async def main():
    # await db.create_db()  # Создание базы данных
    (подключение пула...)
    try:
        bot = Bot(token=Config.TOKEN,default=DefaultBotProperties(parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML))

        dp = Dispatcher(storage=redis_storage)
        dp.message.middleware(ThrottlingMiddleware())
        from Form_Bot import rForm
        from Start_Menu import rCom
        dp.include_routers(
            rForm,
            rCom
        )
    finally:
        await close.pool()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())

Много чего убрал из функции async def main для наглядности, однако смысл тот же.
Как в данном случае вынести bot за рамки данного файла, чтобы его можно было использовать где угодно?
Написать:
bot = Bot(token=Config.TOKEN, default=DefaultBotProperties(parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML))

в начале файла Main не вариант.

Вы всегда можете сделать функцию, которая создаёт и возвращает экземпляр Bot. А потом передавать этот экземпляр в любые другие классы и функции своего проекта. В явном виде. Или в виде полей классов при создании их экземпляров.

@CrazyElf, в таком случае придется в других файлах использовать эту функцию, а значит и экземпляр бот будет по новой создаваться, не совсем подходящее решение

Инициализируйте в одном файле, поместите в переменную, а там где нужно импортируйте её. Чтото типа: from cfg import bot

@Amgarak будет ли хорошим решение после импортов прописать bot=None, затем в функции main объявить global bot, после чего сделать инициализацию?

А зачем? Просто заинициализировать в отдельном конфигурационном файле, а где нужно уже импортировать и сразу пользовать без всяких глобалов.

Если вы хотите использовать более "чистую" архитектуру и иметь доступ к объекту бота из разных мест, то советую вам следовать принципам Dependency Injection (DI) используя dishka, так как это будет отличным решением.
